# How to remove last name field in account detail ? (not checkout field)

Tags: woocommerce

I’d like to remove the last name filed in account details page.I try to edit form-edit-account.php file and delete the last name field.It removed, but I can’t save it. There is a message “the last name is a required field” .How to remove it?
I try hook, but it didn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'remove_billing_fields' );
function remove_billing_fields( $fields ) {
         unset($fields['billing_last_name']);
         return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, it worked for me.

In your child theme's functions.php add the following to remove the **required** attribute to account_first_name and account_last_name inputs.

```
/*WOOCOMMERCE UNSET REQUIRED FIELD IN EDIT ACCOUNT*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields' , 
'smtl_edit_account_remove_required_names' );
  function smtl_edit_account_remove_required_names( $fields ) {
   unset($fields['account_first_name']);
   unset($fields['account_last_name']);
   return $fields;
}
```

Then, you can simply hide the fields with some css

```
.woocommerce-EditAccountForm .woocommerce-form-row--last,
.woocommerce-EditAccountForm .woocommerce-form-row--first {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is information with instructions about that: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-last-name-field-1/#post-7637397

Comment: Thanks,I have try this instruction,but it's not what I want. I means last name in Account Details page.http://i.imgur.com/CbhVS2B.jpg